# How can I check for statistical significance from an unknown distribution?

Tags: statistics

I am trying some analysis on the Titanic data set. I want to check if women and children are treated equally when it comes to rescuing them from the Titanic. I have found the following data, that all relates to women and children between classes 1, 2 and 3:

$\begin{matrix}
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Total} & \textbf{Survived}\\
1 & 142 & 121\\
2 & 101 & 92\\
3 & 168 & 81
\end{matrix}$

The data is not normally distributed. What can I do?

Comment: Does "total" represent the total women and children, or total people (including men)?  Without any data on the number of men, you cannot compare to men. Without giving specifics on numbers of children versus numbers of women, you cannot compare children to women.  The only thing that can be said here is that it looks like class 3 people had more trouble surviving as compared to classes 1 and 2.

Comment: @Michael No the total is the total of women and children, the Survived is the subset of total that actually survived. I do not want to test women and children compared to men, but however I want to test if they are treated equally between classes. 
I want to know if the percentage of people who survived between classes is statistically significant

Comment: Use some kind of chi-squared test?

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{168}$ be the 0/1 survival of each person of class 3, and assume they are i.i.d. Bernoulli with some unknown probability $p_3$, you can use **Hoeffding's inequality** for bounded random variables.  In this case we have $0\leq Z_i\leq 1$ for all $i$ and so
$$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \leq np_3 - t\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{-2t^2}{n}\right) \quad \forall t \geq 0 $$

Now if you consider a hypothesis $p_3\geq 0.6$, then we have
\begin{align}
P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \leq n (.6) - t\right] &\leq P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \leq np_3 - t\right]\\
&\leq \exp\left(\frac{-2t^2}{n}\right) 
\end{align}

In your case you have $n=168$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i=81$. So using $t=19.8$, which is the largest $t$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i\leq 168(0.6)-t$ is true for your **particular** data, we get
$$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{168} Z_i \leq 168 (.6) - 19.8\right] \leq 0.0094$$
So you have good reason to reject the hypothesis $p_3\geq 0.6$. You have even greater reason to reject the hypothesis $p_3\geq 0.7$. On the other hand you have good  reason to accept the hypothesis that the class 1 and 2 survival probabilities were larger than 0.7.

---

In general, if you have bounded random variables that do not have a Gaussian distribution, Hoeffding's inequality is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do. Let us say that $B_1, B_2$ and $B_3$ are three binomial random variables with respective parameters $(n_i, p_i)$ for $i = 1,2,3.$ If $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = p,$ then $B_1 + B_2 + B_3$ is binomial with parameters $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ and $p.$ This means that if your "null hypothesis" (i.e. that hypothesis you want to statistically reject) is $H_0$: the survival rate is the same for all three clases, then you can just add up the tables and find the common maximum likelihood. In your case, you will get $(121+92+81)/(142+101+168) \approx 0.71533.$ Thus, you are assuming $B_1 \sim \mathsf{Bin}(142, 0.71533)$ and similarly for $B_2$ and $B_3;$ furthermore, these are independent variables. You can calculate the expected number for each class, let call them $m_1 = 142 \times 0.71533 \approx 101.58,$ $m_2 \approx 72.25$ and $m_3 \approx 120.18.$ The deviations from the mean are $d_1 = 121-m_1\approx 19.42,$ $d_2 \approx 19.75$ and $d_3 \approx -39.18.$ Hence, what was observed or something more extreme has probability $p = P(|B_1-m_1| \geq d_1)P(|B_2 - m_2|\geq d_2)P(|B_3-m_3|\geq d_3)$ by independence. This probability can be calculated explicitly by a computer without recurring to simulations nor approximations. This is the $p$-value and it tells you to what degree of confidence you can reject the null hypothesis (higher $p$ less confidence and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all for the answers, I did however try something else, maybe you can tell if this is an okay approach.

I went with a chi-squared approach to find a $p$-value between the different categories.

$h_0 = $ There is no change between the survival rates of the groups.

I found the percentage of the overall survivors i.e. $s = 121+92+81 = 294$ and the total number of people $t = 142+101+168 = 411$ and found the percentage of survivors $\text{percent} = \frac{294}{411} \approx 0.72$.

Then used this percentage as the expected survival rate for each class to find an expected number of survivors, for then to perform a chi-squared test to get a $p$-value.

Let me know if this is a bad approach.

Comment: It might be more usual to use a $2\times 3$ contingency table of cabin class and survived/died for your chi-squared test (you would get a substantially higher $\chi^2$ statistic, largely due to the disproportionately high number of those in third class who did not survive)